# undefined method `updated?' for HasOneAssociation , for nested attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-one

so my problem is like:

https://gist.github.com/panSarin/4a221a0923927115584a

when i save this form i get error like in title

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `updated?' for 
#ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation:0x00000008fcacf8>):
```

I checked without polymorphic association - and it`s the same.

When the parent model (BusinessClient in that case) have `belongs_to` then it works fine. But i can't belive that i can't have architecture that children keeps `parent_id` . Any idea what should i change to make it works ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## EDIT

Actually, I had defined the relation twice in my case, once as `belongs_to`, once as `has_one_through`. Long day :) Arthur's answer should be the accepted one!

Previous answer:

```
Just had the same problem and worked it out. I had this:

    has_one :organization, through: :event

I switched it to this: 

    has_one: organization, through: :event, autosave: false
```

I think it might be an ActiveRecord bug.

Autosave [calls `updated?` on associations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6e3ab3e15faf782f6a937ccf5574a4fb63e3e353/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L422), 
which is [defined for `belongs_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94cd08be38dc086714be8f6cbe17e77f778e1ecc/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb#L30), but [not for `has_one`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94cd08be38dc086714be8f6cbe17e77f778e1ecc/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb) (or `has_one_through`).

Comment: I arrived here experiencing the same problem.  Sure enough I had a `belongs_to` and a `has_one` defining the same relationship.  I removed the old `has_one` and now my tests all pass again.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the gist, the error seems to be at the definition of `:client` association:

```
belongs_to :client, foreign_key: :arch_crm_client_id
has_one :client, as: :client_details
```

You are trying to define 2 relations with the same name, that would make ActiveRecord fail. To solve this, you need to rename one of the associations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the correct answer is

```ruby
class BusinessClient < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client, foreign_key: :arch_crm_client_id
  has_one :client_details, class_name: :Client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client

end
```